# Access "No Current Record" error 3021 on form load from SQL data

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a split form which, when only 1 record is present in the underlying query, will exhibit the following behavior:

- Populate with all data from the 1 record
- Give the No Current Record error whenever attempting to manipulate `Me.Recordset` (even though the data is displayed)

This error continues to happen if I either:

- Refresh the form (using F5 or mForm.Refresh)
- Requery with mForm.Requery

However, if I have 2 records returned by the underlying query, switching between the records in the splitform datasheet causes this problem to go away.

I am at a loss for what I can do to stop this from happening with:

- Access 2010
- ODBC linked connection
- SQL server 2008

Is there a way I can trigger something in the `form_load` event to do whatever switching records causes to happen?

Comment: post some code please

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
If(Not(RS.EOF) and Not(RS.BOF)) then
     Do your stuff here.
End if
```

or if you do not like the Not logic then you can go

```
If RS.EOF or RS.BOF then
(*leave this line blank)*
Else:
     Do your stuff here.
End if
```

If you try to move with 1 record then the recordset will end up at EOF (End of File) or BOF (Beginging of file) which means there is no record to display and it will throw an error.

This shouldn't affect the 1 record being displayed.